# Avoiding Round-Trip Key Lookups

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a database table upon which many other tables are dependent, which means I need to obtain a key from it at the earliest possible opportunity. The problem is, this means a round-trip to the database, creating a row in the table if necessary and returning the key, and I'm wondering about whether there are any clever ways to eliminate that step.

Part of the problem is that the column that really uniquely identifies each row is of variable length and has the potential to be quite long, making it unsuitable for use as a key. To give this as an example, imagine all of my data is organised based upon a "domain", for the sake of simplicity assume a website domain. As a result I might have two tables that look like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
    `key` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT X'0000000000000000',
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`key`),
    UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
);
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `domain` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT X'0000000000000000',
    `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`domain`,`username`)
);
```

Currently to handle a domain in this example I would do something like the following:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `domains` (`key`, `name`)
VALUES (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE), a_name);

SELECT `key` FROM `domains` WHERE `name` = a_name;
```

This works well enough, but as you can see it involves a round-trip; in my case I trigger the `INSERT` right away, rather than having to `SELECT` first, check the result and then return for another pass.

#### Predictable Key

One alternative I've already considered is to use a v5 UUID rather than a v1; essentially generating a SHA-1 hash of the `name` column and storing that as the key. This means that the key is always predictable knowing only the `name`, and thus requires no round-trip. Indeed, I can even delay or skip the `INSERT` if I want to.

The problem with this option is that the UUID that is generated is highly random, which isn't ideal for indexing, as it means that even a small set of domains could be spread widely over numerous index pages. Index performance is why, in the above example, I'm using the recommended method of storing a UUID using `UUID_TO_BIN(a_uuid, TRUE)` which reorders v1 UUIDs to improve index performance, so replacing that with a highly random key seems like a poor trade-off, especially if the same basic keys are used widely throughout my database.

#### Caching

The other obvious alternative is to try to cache domain keys in my application, so that no lookup is required for a domain that's already known.

The problem with this is that my application is PHP based, which means my main method for caching this information is to either store it in a file (annoying, but doable) or in a user's `$_SESSION` array. The latter, while easiest, is dependent upon always having a session ID available, which isn't guaranteed; i.e- in the worst case where no request includes one, I'm still doing the full round-trip each time.

#### Question

I've been banging my head on this for a while, as none of the options exactly jump out at me as ideal, and I can't help but shake the feeling that there may be a clever solution I'm unaware of.

So my question is; what is the simplest method of avoiding this round-trip for key retrieval? Are there alternatives or improvements to what I've already considered (e.g- ways to avoid the problems I've identified)?

A solution to this problem should either eliminate the round-trip entirely, or eliminate the need for it in most cases.

If necessary I can try to furnish more details of my actual system, but really the example above should cover it; i.e- before I can do anything involving the `users` table, I need to determine the domain key that I need my queries.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with this option is that the UUID that is generated is highly random, which isn't ideal for indexing, as it means that even a small set of domains could be spread widely over numerous index pages. Index performance is why...

I am thinking that this might be a case of premature optimization. An index created for a set will maintain adjacent keys in the same page regardless of the number of missing keys between them. Don't try to out think the database. Its optimizations will be correct for 99% of the cases, even when you have sparse keys.

> So I have a database table upon which many other tables are dependent, which means I need to obtain a key from it at the earliest possible opportunity. The problem is, this means a round-trip to the database, creating a row in the table if necessary and returning the key, and I'm wondering about whether there are any clever ways to eliminate that step.

Most databases have a way to automatically assign sequential ID's to a column. In the case of `MySQL` that method is `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns. Set the `key` column in your primary table to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, and do not provide a value for that column on `INSERT`. Then followup inserts can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to provide a value for the foreign key column. It would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
    `key` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`key`),
    UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
);
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `domainid` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`domain`,`username`)
);
INSERT INTO `domain` (`name`)
    VALUES ('example.com');
INSERT INTO `users` (`domainid`,`username`,`email`)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'henryg','henryg@gmail.com');
```

No extra trip to the server, the server keeps track of the last inserted id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; unfortunately I can't rely on `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, as other `INSERT` queries may run before I actually use the ID, though I suppose there may be a way around that if I put ID's in variables in a predictable fashion?

As for index optimisation; MySQL have recommended for some time to reorder UUID's, and only relatively recently (MySQL 8 iirc) added `UUID_TO_BIN()` which supports reordering, so I have to assume there's a reason for it. The actual table I'm working with is going to have to handle a lot of rows (so index performance will be important).